# How can I get Android Studio to forget its location for CMake.exe?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake

I sent an Android Studio 3 project to another person for assistance.  He uses different drive letters.  Since I got the project back, whenever I try to clean the project, I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'E:\Android\SDK\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe''
```

I need to change that E:\ to C:.  When I grep for it and do so, Android Studio just changes it back to E.

Where do I change this so that it won't put it back to E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is just my particular case, but posting it here in case it helps anyone else.  Clean didn't work, invalidating cache didn't work.

I had to manually delete the following folders:

.idea

.gradle

build (in all places)

.externalNativeBuild

Somewhere in those was the cache with this information in it.  After deleting them and restarting AS, it demanded some gradle re-build and then everything was okay.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple paths to this. A lot of modern projects are set up through the build script, and not IDE/project settings in the IDE, as in traditional projects. If so, take a look if he changed something in your gradle/maven/whatever you use.

Otherwise take look into any iml-files in the project and/or the .idea folder, if you cannot find it in File->Settings and/or File->Project Structure.

If you have a Bash installed (e.g. git-bash) you could try doing a "grep"-command in the project folder to find the reference.

And the easiest solution. If you use git or another version control system, then look through the changes of your files. If the file in question is under version control then it will show up there. If that is the case, consider removing it, machine/developer specific settings should often not be under the version control of the project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.  I did grep for it-- it's only found in one file, that being "android_gradle_clean_2.command.txt".  I believe that file is rebuilt when you execute anything, though, since whenever I go ahead and change e:\ to c:\, it simply restores it back to e:\ immediately.

I figure somewhere there must be a cached copy of this.  There are copies in c:\users\[myname]\.gradle ... but when I rename that folder, it re-downloads gradle and the e:\ actually COMES BACK. 

I'm quite baffled at this point!

Comment: If it's a cache there's File->Invalidated Caches/Restart, however, if the problem started after copying the project files to somewhere else and then back, I doubt (I won't rule it out yet, just considering it unlikely) it's a cache. I'll install Android studio specifically now, and see what I can find :) so far I've just gone by general IntelliJ experience

Comment: That didn't help me much. Only thing I found is that is you link C++ projects with gradle it will ask for a cmake location. I suspect you need to find some kind of NDK settings or similar :/ Sorry I can't be of any more help